# How to put Javascript variable into an html page

Tags: javascript, html

I got this line in html :

```
<input type="text" name="number" value= "" style="width: 20px;border:#FFFFFF none 0px;" readonly></p>
```

And I also have a variable in a function in javascript that I would like to put in the value of the html line.

Comment: What you mean is var readonly?

Comment: Where is that function?

Comment: This is a text area where I only want to display my variable so I put readonly.

Comment: The function is on the same page : `function countChecked(){
      var Cpt = 0;
   var els = document.getElementsByName('eleveCoche[]');
   
   for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++)
   { 
    if ( els[i].checked )
    {  
     Cpt ++; 
    } 
   } 
  }`

Comment: Despite it is readonly, through javascript, you can **always** edit its value. if you mind about the fact that it is readonly and want to remove it, just set readonly to false through javascript. In any case, please post your function first. Also, just a side note, unless your input is inside a <p>, you have an extra </p> at the end of your input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access JavaScript variables in JSP as below:

**JavaScript:**

```
 var fruit = "Apple";
 $("#someTextBox").val(fruit);
```

**JSP:**

```
<input type="text" id ="someTextBox" name="number" style="width: 20px;border:#FFFFFF none 0px;"></p>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so I wrote this in my function : `function countChecked(){
      var Cpt = 0;
   var els = document.getElementsByName('eleveCoche[]');
   
   for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++)
   { 
    if ( els[i].checked )
    {  
     Cpt ++; 
      $("#someTextBox").val(Cpt);
    } 
   } 
  }` And I put the id like you did : `<input type="text" id="someTextBox" name="number" style="width: 20px;border:#FFFFFF none 0px;" readonly></p>` But it doesn't work, do you know why ?

Comment: Can you check if `els[i].checked` is `true`?

Comment: Yes I checked by putting an `alert Cpt` and it showed the result

Comment: But it doesn't work anymore when I put `$("#someTextBox").val(Cpt);`

Comment: Can you check if you have `jquery` inlcuded in you `JSP` page

Comment: I put `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to include JSP. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, but better to download the file, put it in your `webapp` and make a `src` refer to that path.

Comment: Ah okay but I heard that it's not so good because it will make the server work harder uselessly

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/6v28hj75/1/

```
function myFunction() {
input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
input.value = "Your value here"; 
}
myFunction()
```

I made you a simple example, pure Javascript.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I call my function on the html line because when I write `value = myFunction` it displays myFunction and not the result

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use jQuery like this :

```js
jQuery(function($){
  
  var foo = 'bar';
  
  $('input[name="number"]').val(foo);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="number" value="">
```